# Showing a dialog on all pages after rendering is done

Tags: dialog, aurelia

I'm trying to add a popup that's supposed to be displayed when the user naviagates to a new page if certain conditions are met. The problem is that even if I add a post render step to the router configuration, on views that are composed by several custom elements they sometimes import resources after the post render step has executed which causes the popup to dissapear and pretty much lock the page. This is a small reproducable example:

```
router.configure(config => {
    config.addPostRenderStep(CustomPostRenderStep);
    return config;
});
```

...

```
@inject(DialogService)
class CustomPostRenderStep{
    constructor(
        private mDialogService: DialogService
    ) {
    }

    run(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next) {
        this.mDialogService.open({
            viewModel: TestModal
            lock: true
        });

        return next();
    }
}
```

The popup will on some pages appear on the screen for a brief moment before it disappears but the body html tag will still have the class "ux-dialog-open".

Adding a timeout helps, but how long the timeout needs to be is different on different systems which makes it an unreliable solution. Like this:

```
@inject(DialogService)
class CustomPostRenderStep{
    constructor(
        private mDialogService: DialogService
    ) {
    }

    run(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next) {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.mDialogService.open({
                viewModel: TestModal
                lock: true
            });
        }, 200);

        return next();
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to wait for everything to be rendered before displaying the popup?

Comment: does the attached() callback work?

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to utilize events fired by router after navigation success

https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/09/understanding-aurelia-router-events/

you can subscribe to `router:navigation:success` in your app and create your dialog aferwards

router:navigation:success

Comment: This has the same issue as the addPostRenderStep(). I tried subscribing to the event and adding a test log in the callback. When using verboser logging in the Chrome console I see:

...,
"DEBUG [templating] importing resources for...",
"DEBUG [templating] importing resources for...",
"DEBUG [templating] importing resources for...",
"TEST LOG",
"DEBUG [templating] importing resources for...",
"DEBUG [templating] importing resources for...",

So the callback executes before the page is fully done loading

Comment: "You are holding it wrong" then.
do you return promises from your activate methods?

Answer (score 0):

You should use TaskQueue in order to be called on the next rendering loop.
See: http://aurelia.io/docs/api/task-queue/class/TaskQueue/method/queueTask

This should work:

```
@inject(DialogService, TaskQueue)
class CustomPostRenderStep {
  constructor(
    private mDialogService: DialogService
        private mTaskQueue: TaskQueue
  ) {
  }

  run(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next) {
    this.mTaskQueue.queueTask(() => {
      this.mDialogService.open({
        viewModel: TestModal,
        lock: true
      });
    });
    return next();
  }
}
```

I do not really know the RenderPipeline very well but maybe you could call `next()` inside your queued task.

Comment: This has the same issue as my current solution. The popup will be displayed briefly before disappearing

Comment: What about the other answer?

Comment: I don't really see how it differs from my original solution. The gist you provided works fine but as I said in my post, the problem arises in views where you have a lot of <require> and the modal starts being displayed before all components has been loaded in the page.

Comment: I try to help so may be you can take some time to reproduce your issue in the Gist and maybe someone will help you to find the real issue behind and fix it... If you want help at least provide some test case in order to investigate because even if you mentioned that the issue happens "sometimes" your example not provide keys to reproduce it. And I have started a new answer in order to investigate on your issue since this one is not satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

View my Gist fork that is working, maybe you should investigate what is closing your dialog by setting breakpoints in aurelia-dialog code.

**Here's an example: [Aurelia Router Demo | PostRenderStep modal dialog example](https://gist.run?id=51808646f0840b191ec3fd4651587c71)**

**app.js**

```js
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { DialogService } from 'aurelia-dialog';
import { TestModal} from 'test-modal';

export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([
      {route: ['', 'home'], name: 'home', moduleId: 'home/home', nav: true, title: 'Home'},
      {route: 'profile', name: 'profile', moduleId: 'profile/profile', nav: true, title: 'Profile'},
      {route: 'settings', name: 'settings', moduleId: 'settings/settings', nav: true, title: 'Settings'}
    ]);
    config.addPostRenderStep(PostRenderStep);
    this.router = router;
  }
}

@inject(DialogService, TestModal)
class PostRenderStep {
  constructor(dialogService, testModal){
    this.dialogService = dialogService;
    this.testModal = testModal;
  }

  run(routingContext, next) {
    this.dialogService.open({
      viewModel: TestModal,
      lock: true
    });

    return next();
  }
}
```

Plus, which versions are you using?